# Setando um Field para uma Proxy

Tags: java, reflexão, proxy

Olá, eu estou com um problema: eu preciso trocar o valor de um Field para uma proxy.

Meu proxy funciona perfeitamente, mas eu não consigo modificar um Field. Sempre que eu tento me retorna um IllegalArgumentException dizendo que eu não posso setar o Field de tal tipo pra Proxy.

Meu objetivo é setar esse Field sem precisar de nenhum import, ou seja, sem extender ou implementar qualquer coisa.

Exemplo do que está acontecendo:

```
 public class ClasseAlvo {
      Classe2 con;
 }
```

Eu preciso setar a variável "con" através de uma Proxy feita da "Classe2", a proxy é feita com sucesso e meu problema é setar a variável com a minha proxy.

```
public class ClasseProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    Object pc;
    public ClasseProxy(Object original) {
        this.pc = original;
    }

    public Object invocaFuncao(Method m, Object[] args) {
        try {
            return pc.getClass().getMethod(m.getName(), m.getParameterTypes()).invoke(pc, args);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("teste")) {
            System.out.println("Metodo teste foi executado.");
        } else {
            return invocaFuncao(m, args);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

E minha interface:

```
public interface IClasse {
    public void teste(String nome);
}
```

Minha proxy e onde está o erro:

```
IClasse pc = (IClasse)Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(),
                                                  new Class[] {IClasse.class},
                                                  new ClasseProxy(obj));
Field f = alvo.getClass().getDeclaredField("con");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(alvo, pc); // <--- O PROBLEMA
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: Poderia mostrar o trecho do código que está com problema?

Comment: Editado com o código (versão mais limpa) pra mostrar o meu problema. Também queria saber se é possível fazer o que eu estou tentando fazer e se tem outra forma pra isso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a solução depois de muito tempo procurando.
A CGLib tem uma ótima API pra uso de Proxies.

Comecei a ler sobre [aqui](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbNov2005.html)

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram de alguma forma.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está criando um proxy para `IClasse` e tentando colocar numa propriedade do tipo `Classe2`.

Só para relembrar um pouco de polimorfismo: você pode atribuir um tipo mais específico para uma variável mais genérica, mas **não** pode atribuir um tipo mais genérico em uma variável de um tipo mais específico.

Então, isso pode:

```java
IClasse obj = objetoDoTipoClasse2;
```

Mas isso **não** pode:

```java
Classe2 obj = objetoDoTipoIClasse;
```

Coloquei o seu código num projeto de teste e com uma única alteração ele passou a funcionar. A alteração foi na `ClasseAlvo`, mudando o tipo do atributo para `IClasse`, assim:

```java
public class ClasseAlvo {
    IClasse con;
}
```

Comment: Como eu havia dito, eu não posso mudar a ClasseAlvo nem a Classe2, eu teria que fazer tudo através de reflection. Mas eu já achei a solução usando a CGLib, muito útil pra quem quer usar Proxies. De qualquer jeito, obrigado pela resposta, ela deve ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Senão me engano, nesse caso a 'Classe2' deve implementar a interface 'IClasse', certo?

Você poderia tentar fazer:

IClasse pc = (Classe2)Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(),
                                                  new Class[] {IClasse.class},
                                                  new ClasseProxy(obj));

Caso o 'Classe2' esteja implementando 'IClasse'...

vlw

Comment: Como eu havia dito, eu preciso interagir com a Classe2 e a ClasseAlvo sem nenhum "import", tudo por proxy, sendo que as classes não são minhas e não posso simplesmente adicionar um "implements" nela... Não sei se tem como fazer isso do jeito que quero fazer, ou se talvez tenha outro modo de fazer a mesma coisa. É isso que eu quero saber.